# How to create a photo sharing activity?

Tags: android

How can I create a custom activity that can be chosen by the user via the share option when viewing the photo gallery? I have options like "Share with Facebook, Twitter, FlickR" etc. But I want to add my own option in there.

i.e. Go to "Photos", then click the "Share" button. You will be presented with a bunch of share providers. What do I need to do to get my activity in there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After taking a look at the built-in Mail application I spotted this section in the AndroidManifest.xml (thanks Janusz).

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

My app now shows up in the list :)

Comment: Now your app will also show up in every other send list. If your app is only for image sharing you should use the correct mime type.

Comment: Yeah thanks Janusz - I've changed it just to android:mimeType="image" now.

Comment: Specifying `android:mimeType="image"` gives a android.content.IntentFilter$MalformedMimeTypeException; you need to instead specify `android:mimeType="image/*"`

Answer (score 1):

I trigger this dialog with invoking the following code:

```
Intent shareImage = new Intent();
shareImage.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
String mimeTyp = "image/png";
shareImage.setType(mimeTyp);
shareImage.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(image));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareImage, "Share Image"));
```

this shows that you need to create an [Intent Filter](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html#ifs) for the action send and all the image types that you want to catch.

I haven't tested it but I think you can add the following intent filter to the activity that you want to handle the send image intent:

```
<intent-filter ...>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
   <data android:mimeType="image/png" android:scheme="http"... />
   .
   .
   .
</intent-filter>
```

I'm not totally sure about the complete configuration of the filter but I think you can figure out the rest yourself.

Comment: But this is just to start an action is it not? I want to insert my own activity into the share image activity. So if the user goes to "Photos" on their phone, then clicks "Share", they get a list of applications they can share their photo with. I want my application to be in there.